# Flutter : How to persist File content upon application uninstall?

Tags: android, flutter

I created a class to store a data in a file, so that I can refer the data again the next time I open the apps.

Sample code are as follows:

```
 static Future<String> get localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }
```

```
  static Future<File> get localFile async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String fileName = 'file01';
    final path = await localPath;
    return File('$path/$fileName.txt');
  }
```

```
  static Future<String> readContent() async {
    try {
      final file = await localFile;
      String contents = await file.readAsString();
      return contents;
    } catch (e) {
      return "null";
    }
  }
```

Write method

```
  static Future<File> writeContent(String content) async {
    final file = await localFile;
    var result = readContent();
    return file.writeAsString('$content', mode: FileMode.append);
  }
```

writeContent() method will be triggered on some events in the apps. It will create a file if it does not existed, and append a new data if it does.

After I uninstalled the apps, the readContent() gives me "null" response. Any idea on how to persist the File?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, uninstalling an app deletes all files and directories associated with it.

I would store the files in a database and, in case you need them locally, download them when the user first opens the app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would try to store the file in the device's external storage first because the apps that I am currently working on can be ran in offline, so I am trying to avoid using any cloud database.